# Period of an oscillation of a stick on a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

System is at rest. If I pull the rod a little bit it will start to oscilliate. I want to find frequency of the oscillation. What should be my approach?

edit 1: I have added my approach

What I did was this. I said $$ F= kx= \frac{mg}{2} $$ so if move the end a little bit I will have the following equation for restoring force $$ kx=\frac{mg}{2}$$ this  implies $$k=\frac{mg}{2}x $$ and $$\rm{restoring ~force} = \frac{mg}{2x}\Delta x $$ if this is true I can solve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED - fixed error pointed out by Sammy Gerbil***

The answer depends on whether the rod is fixed at the wall, or whether it pivots.

If it pivots, you have a system with a certain moment of inertia $I=\frac13 m \ell^2$ and a torque that is a function of displacement $\Gamma = -kx\ell = k\theta\ell^2$ for small angles $\theta$ from the equilibrium position. The frequency then follows from the usual equation of motion for a simple harmonic oscillating system:

$$I\ddot\theta = -k\theta\ell^2$$
Putting $I=\frac13 m \ell^2$ we get
$$m\theta=-3k\theta\implies\\
\omega = \sqrt{\frac{3k}{m}}$$

When the rod is fixed to the wall, things are much more complex. You need to know the dimensions and elastic properties of the rod to compute its frequency in the absence of the spring; then you have to solve the stress/strain equation when the spring is added. This is seriously hard work. It's unlikely, given how you pose the question ("this is a high school level problem"), that that is what is expected of you...